# WordPress AJAX File Upload - FrontEnd

Tags: jquery, ajax, uploads, forms, front-end

So I have been reading through every WordPress front-end AJAX file upload tutorial I can fine. Nothing is working for me at the moment. The one that makes the most sense to me is this one: http://theaveragedev.com/wordpress-files-ajax/

Here is my code:

In my template file example.php

```
<script>var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"</script>
<form id="file_form">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax_file_nonce', 'security'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_file_upload">
    <label for="file_upload">It's a file upload...</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

This is in ajax-file-upload.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var form_data = {};
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        form_data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#file_form').ajaxForm({
        url: ajax_url, // there on the admin side, do-it-yourself on the front-end
        data: form_data,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });
});
```

This is in my functions.php

```
function q_scripts(){
    $src = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ajax-file-upload.js';
    wp_enqueue_script('my_ajax_file_uploader_thing', $src, array('jquery', 'jquery-form'));
}
add_action('init', 'q_scripts');

function handle_file_upload(){
    check_ajax_referer('ajax_file_nonce', 'security');

    if(!(is_array($_POST) && is_array($_FILES) && defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)){
        return;
    }

    if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);

    $response = array();

    foreach($_FILES as $file){
        $file_info = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);

        // do something with the file info...
        $response['message'] = 'Done!';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_file_upload', 'handle_file_upload');
```

I have tried adding the enctype to the form element and this didn't work. The error I keep getting is an alert saying 'undefined'. Does anyone know how I can correct this issue?

**EDIT**

The 'undefined' issue has now gone away as I editied the js file to have a click event and changed the selector for the form input loop:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#file_form :submit').click(function() {
        var form_data = {};
        $('#file_form').find('input').each(function () {
            form_data[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(form_data);
        $('#file_form').ajaxForm({
            url: ajax_url, // there on the admin side, do-it-yourself on the front-end
            data: form_data,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.message);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The files still aren't being uploaded to the media folder. I also want to get the uploaded URL back once it has uploaded.

I am writing to the console the file object so I can see what is happening. Here is an example of it:

```
Object {security: "e6db2a6eee", _wp_http_referer: "/chat?sessionappid=138", action: "my_file_upload", file_upload: "C:\fakepath\download.jpg", "": "Go"}
```

Is there something wrong with this and is that why it isn't uploading?

Comment: You're missing the action parameter in your js. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Hi Shane (aren't you BuddyPress Shane?). The action parameter is passed as a hidden field in the form. I've decided to use a different solution. I'm using Simple Ajax Upload to upload the files to a different directory.

Answer (score 13):

Hi You have Use this COde For WordPress front-end AJAX file upload tutorial Code
Here is my code:

In my template file example.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="support_title" class="support-title">
   <input type="file" id="sortpicture" name="upload">
   <input class="save-support" name="save_support" type="button" value="Save">
 </form>
```

This is in ajax-file-upload.js

```
      jQuery(document).on('click', '.save-support', function (e) {

                        var supporttitle = jQuery('.support-title').val();

                        var querytype = jQuery('.support-query').val();
                        var file_data = jQuery('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];

                        var form_data = new FormData();
                        if (supporttitle == '') {
                            jQuery('.support-title').css({"border": "1px solid red"})
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            jQuery('.support-title').css({"border": "1px solid #e3ecf0"})
                        }

                        form_data.append('file', file_data);
                        form_data.append('action', 'md_support_save');
                        form_data.append('supporttitle', supporttitle);

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                            type: 'post',
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function (response) {
                                jQuery('.Success-div').html("Form Submit Successfully")
                            },  
                            error: function (response) {
                             console.log('error');
                            }

                        });
                    });

                });
```

This iS functions.php code

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_md_support_save','md_support_save' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_md_support_save','md_support_save' );


  function md_support_save(){
       $support_title = !empty($_POST['supporttitle']) ? 
       $_POST['supporttitle'] : 'Support Title';

        if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
           require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
       }
      // echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
      $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
      $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
      $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);

    // echo $movefile['url'];
      if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])) {
         echo "File Upload Successfully";
    } else {
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
         */
        echo $movefile['error'];
    }
    die();
 }
```

Comment: Is that a question or an answer? Please do not post code dumps without any explanation.

Comment: ok we have update my code and this ans for WordPress front-end AJAX file upload tutorial

Comment: The answer works fine. Why this is not marked as right answer? There is an error in js code. original was --> }error: and the correct one is }, error: (missed the comma after })

Comment: Wow.. This worked foe me!. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<form id="article_form" name="article_form" class="wordpress-ajax-form" method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          <input type="file" name="uploadedfiles" id="uploadedfiles"  accept="image/*"  >
          <br>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_action">
          <br>
          <button>Send</button>
       </form>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".wordpress-ajax-form").submit(function(evt){  

  evt.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: $('#article_form').attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
    // alert(response);
    alert('Article created Successfully!!!');
    }
  });
  return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> all codes for function.php

---

```
if (!empty($_POST) || (!empty($_FILES))) {
    require_once (ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once (ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Upload Exhibitor Logo
        $file = $_FILES['uploaded_doc'];
        if (!empty($file)) {
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            // Create 'user_avatar' directory if not exist
            $folderPath = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/Reports';
            if (!file_exists($folderPath)) {
                mkdir($folderPath, 0777, true);
            }

                 $ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['uploaded_doc']['name'])));            
                if( $ext== 'pdf' || $ext== 'docx' ){                    
                $ABSPATH_userAvatarFullImage = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/Reports/' . time() . '.' . $ext;
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_doc']['tmp_name'], $ABSPATH_userAvatarFullImage)) {                        
                    $data = array(
                    'title' => $_POST['title'],
                    'arabic_title' => $_POST['arabic_title'],
                    'principle_investigators' => $_POST['principle_investigators'],
                    'co_investgators' => $_POST['co_investgators'],
                    'coverage_area' => $_POST['coverage_area'],
                    'publication_year' => $_POST['publication_year'],
                    'types' => $_POST['types'],
                    'uploaded_doc' => $_FILES['uploaded_doc']['name'],
                    'create_date'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s') 

                    );          
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "reports_publication";         
        $result = $wpdb->insert($table, $data);

                }
                echo "1";
                }else{
                    echo "File not in format";
                }

        }


}
}
```

}

Comment: need an explanation